# How to implement <a> tag in bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

[Demo JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ettmujvg/8/):

I can't implement the `href` into the buttons.

It will work if I put it this way :

```
<a href="/">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-custom">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <br />
        <span class="btntext glyphicon-class">PP bậc thang</span>
    </button>
</a>
```

But this will result in this mess :

[image]

Is there any simple way I can fix this? Thanks alot!

Comment: Why not simply to add `class="btn btn-default btn-custom"`  your  `href` element

Comment: @Tibbers Can I ? OMG

Comment: bootstap & twitter-bootstrap are different things, please don't confuse the tags

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apply the btn class to the a instead.

```
<a href="/" class="btn btn-default" ...
```

Also take a look at [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please accept an answer asap. Thanks!

Comment: I'll when it reaches the eligible time, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle for the buttons to work properly:http://jsfiddle.net/ettmujvg/9/

```
 <a href="#"  class="btn btn-default btn-custom">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <br />
      <span class="btntext glyphicon-class">PP bậc thang</span>
 </a>
```